how to take production build in Nextjs
I have created Nextjs application, I am using dynamic page store/[slug]/page.js but I am using this "use client"; import { useState } from 'react'; but could not take build how to solve facing this issue Error: Page "/store/[slug]/page" cannot use both "use client" and export function "generateStaticParams()"
I have created Nextjs application
